# check if current is the main page react-native-webview

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I have a WebView project of an PHP admin panel, that I put a custom Back Button on top of its WebView. I want this button to be visible only if the current screen can go back, which is any screen beside main screen, and in this case our main screen is a admin panel login page. So I came up with the code I shared below.

It works fine, unless you login with wrong credentials. The Back Button immediately shows up when the login button pressed inside the WebView because it gets to another url from admin.panel/login to admin.panel/login/login, but it shouldn't render unless we successfully login to the panel. How can I achieve that?

BackButton.js

```
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const BackButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={props.onPress}>
      <Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={24} color="black" />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Platform, BackHandler, View } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import MyStatusBar from "./components/MyStatusBar";
import MyBackButton from "./components/BackButton";

export default function App() {
  const webViewRef = useRef();

  // to handle goBack function for both button and hardwareBackPress
  const onBackPress = () => {
    if (webViewRef.current) {
      webViewRef.current.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  // to check if current can go back
  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = React.useState(false);

  // WebView does not support swipe back for some android devices
  // thus we have to handle the goBack function with hardwareBackPress
  useEffect(() => {
    ...
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MyStatusBar />
      <WebView
        allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback
        ref={webViewRef}
        source={{ uri: "https://admin.panel/login" }}
        style={styles.webView}
        onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => setCanGoBack(navState.canGoBack)}
      />
      {canGoBack? (
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <MyBackButton onPress={onBackPress} />
        </View>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you have control of the website I think you'd have to communicate with react native via `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage?.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ type: 'canGoBack', payload: true/false }))` to tell it if it can go back or not and handle this in RN via the `onMessage` prop

Comment: Thank you for answering. That is a very good approach actually. If the login is successful, backend can send a message with payload being true. I have no idea how we're gonna get that message in RN but we'll figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. I meant `window.ReactNativeWebView?.postMessage(...)`